# Invalid Character Constant in Java?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/*

Medium Speed
Air 1100 feet per second
Water 4900 feet per second
Steel 16,400 feet per second

Write a program that asks the user to enter "air", "water", or "steel", and the distance that a sound wave will
travel in the medium. The program should then display the amount of time it will take.
You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in air with the following formula:

Time = Distance / 1100
You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in water with the following formula:

Time = Distance / 4900
You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in steel with the following formula:

Time = Distance / 16400
*/

public class SpeedOfSound
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
      {


        String input;   
        char timeTraveled;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        double distance;
        double time;
        double time2;
        double time3;
        time = (distance/ 1100);
        time2 = (distance/ 4900);
        time3 = (distance/ 16400);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");



                System.out.println("Enter air, water, or steel: ");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter distance: ");
                distance = keyboard.nextDouble();



               switch(timeTraveled)
               {
                case 'air':

                System.out.printf("The total time traveled is " + formatter.format(time) + ".");
                break;

                case "water":


                System.out.printf("The total time traveled is " + formatter.format(time2) + ".");
                break;

                case "steel":


                System.out.printf("The total time traveled is " + formatter.format(time3) + "seconds.");
                timeTraveled = input.charAt(0);
                break;
                keyboard.close();
    }
} // main()
}  // class SpeedOfSound
```

Why is `case 'air':` giving me the error `invalid character constant` twice? My professor has a different example for a different program and it's almost the same as what I'm doing but he doesn't get the error. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Hey guy's thanks for the quick responses, I'll fix the mess with the timeTraveled, as I was following my professor's example and forgot to erase that part. (erasing it doesn't do anything btw). Also, when I do put quotation marks around air water and steel it gives me the error "Type mismatch, cannot convert from string to char"

Comment: You're trying to switch (char) timeTraveled  with mixed types. char and String. You can't do that. Declare timeTraveled to type String and wrap air in double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You've got several problems here.

First, single quotes are reserved for single characters, like `'a'`.  Whole strings need to be placed in double quotes.

Second, `timeTraveled` is never assigned anything anyway by the time you use it, so it "might" not have been initialized by the time you try to run it (and get things to compile).  You probably want to use `input` instead.

This is to say, as long as you're using Java 7 or newer, you should write this as your switch argument:

```
switch(input) {
    // statements to follow
}
```

I'm not sure what that assignment at the end of your `"steel"` case is meant to do, but you may want to move its logic out of the `switch` statement entirely.

Answer (score 1):

In some programming languages, single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) are interchangeable. In Java (and also in C and C++), they are not.

If you want to specify a multi-character string literal, use *double* quotes: `"air"`.

Additionally, it is not clear what do expect to happen when you compare a `char` (`timeTraveled`) to a string (`"air"`).

Comment: @KickButtowski what do you mean..it accept chat .it accept only primitives.not objects

Comment: @KickButtowski in that example 
int month = 8; it's primitive

Comment: @getlost thank you for that. because of you I am more updated :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand the logic of this program. If U need to enter the word and then do something depending on it try to make something like

```
String timeTraveled;
if (timeTraveled.equals("air")){
  //do something
} else if (timeTraveled.equals("water")) {
  //do something
} ...
```

Comment: of couse that's the easiest way than go to enum

Comment: With Java 7, both of those expressions are equivalent (except for the capitalization of `string`, since this is Java and not C#).

Comment: Don't use `if`/`else if`/`else` in a situation so well suited for `switch`

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX try to use switch and pass String to switch and see what happens

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX, switch(type : String) is not supported in Java

Comment: @getlost:  You're not still using Java 6, are you?  In Java 7 you most certainly can switch on `String`.  To put it tersely:  "good things" will happen if you do that in Java 7.

Comment: Java 7 and 8 support String in switch cases. It's about time you update to 8

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple issue in your code:

1. It should be `"air"` not `'air'` (solution for your op).
2. Datatype of `timeTraveled` is `char` but you are trying to match it with String (like "air", "water", etc.).
3. `timeTraveled` is not initialized.
4. `distance` is not initialized while doing calculation for `time`, `time1` & `time2`.
5. `keyboard.close();` is unreachable code. Move it outside the `switch` block or add it in `default` case.

Ideally, you should be using chars in your switch case or create `enum` for better clarity.

Comment: air water cannot declared as char .op should definitely use  enum

Answer (score 0):

@justaregularguy - You are getting this error because you have taken air as a character.

mention air as String and you will be fine.
This will help you to - in case you will try non permitted values.

"Cannot switch on a value of type Float. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted"

Answer (score -1):

`'air'` is using single quotes. Single quotes denote a **character** constant. What you're looking for is `"air"`, a **String** constant.

You seem to be a new programmer. I made some improvements to your program, and I'll show you them here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/*
Medium Speed
Air 1100 feet per second
Water 4900 feet per second
Steel 16,400 feet per second

Write a program that asks the user to enter "air", "water", or "steel", and the distance that a sound wave will
travel in the medium. The program should then display the amount of time it will take.
You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in air with the following formula:

Time = Distance / 1100
You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in water with the following formula:

Time = Distance / 4900
You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in steel with the following formula:

Time = Distance / 16400
*/

public class SpeedOfSound {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        char timeTraveled; //what is this even doing here?

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double time = (distance/ 1100);
        double time2 = (distance/ 4900);
        double time3 = (distance/ 16400);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

                System.out.println("Enter air, water, or steel: ");
                String material = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter distance: ");
                double distance = scanner.nextDouble();

                switch (material) {
                    case "air":
                        System.out.printf("The total time traveled is " + formatter.format(time) + ".");
                        break;

                    case "water":
                        System.out.printf("The total time traveled is " + formatter.format(time2) + ".");
                        break;

                    case "steel":
                        System.out.printf("The total time traveled is " + formatter.format(time3) + "seconds.");
                        timeTraveled = material.charAt(0); //what is this even doing here?
                    break;
                }
                scanner.close();
    } // main()
}  // class SpeedOfSound
```

- Made the spacing and indenting more consistent
- Renamed your Scanner object. "keyboard" is not an appropriate name for a Scanner object, since scanner works with not only keyboard input, but also string and file input.
- I combined the *declaration* of your "time" variables and the *definition*

E.g.

```
double time; //a declaration of "time"
time = (distance/ 1100); //a definition of "time"
//becomes:
double time = (distance/ 1100); //a declaration AND definition of "time"
```

- changed `'air'` to `"air"`", also, changed the switch case variable to "material" (which used to be called "input", and is the string that holds the user's input), rather than it using timeTraveled (some miscellaneous character?)

Since your program is only going to be displaying one time of the three possibilities, why calculate all 3? I suggest you rework your algorithm as follows:
Ask the user for the material and distance they want. Set a variable "speed" equal to 1100, 4900, or 16400 depending on the user's choice of air, water or steel. Then, calculate time as distance / speed.

This saves you from repeating 3 identical `System.out.println()` statements, saves you from having 3 time variables (when you only need 1),